# How can I get the size of items returned by scan dynamodb table?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

Dynamodb has a limitation on query that the maximum item is 1MB for a single query. How can I get the total item size from a `query` I send to dynamodb?

Answer (score 1):

If it's the item count you want, you can use `scanResult.getCount()`.

If you want the size of each `scanRequest`, you could write each request to a text file and, when the scan is complete, check the file sizes.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

Best you could do would be to estimate it by counting how many calls to Query() you make till `LastEvaluatedKey` is empty in the response; which indicates the last page of data as been returned.

If all your DDB entries are the same size you could total up `Count`/`Scanned Count` as you make the repeated calls to Query().